# How to check if two permutations are symmetric?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given two permutations `A` and `B` of `L` different elements, `L` is even, let's call these permutations "symmetric" (for a lack of a better term), if there exist `n` and `m`, `m > n` such as (in python notation):

```
 - A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n]
 - B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]
 - all other elements are in place
```

Informally, consider

```
A = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Take any slice of it, for example `1 2`. It starts at the second index and its length is 2. Now take a slice symmetric to it: it ends at the penultimate index and is 2 chars long too, so it's `5 6`. Swapping these slices gives

```
B = 0 5 6 3 4 1 2 7
```

Now, `A` and `B` are "symmetric" in the above sense (`n=1, m=3`). On the other hand

```
A = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
B = 1 0 2 3 4 5 7 6
```

are not "symmetric" (no `n,m` with above properties exist).

How can I write an algorithm in python that finds if two given permutations (=lists) are "symmetric" and if yes, find the `n` and `m`? For simplicity, let's consider only even `L` (because the odd case can be trivially reduced to the even one by eliminating the middle fixed element) and assume correct inputs (`set(A)==set(B), len(set(A))==len(A)`).

(I have no problem bruteforcing all possible symmetries, but looking for something smarter and faster than that).

Fun fact: the number of symmetric permutations for the given `L` is a [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

#### I use [this code](https://gist.github.com/gebrkn/8b73949295853bdaf2b9) to test  out your answers.

Bounty update: many excellent answers here. [@Jared Goguen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35589985/989121) appears to be the fastest.

Final timings:

```
testing 0123456789 L= 10
    test_alexis ok in 15.4252s
    test_evgeny_kluev_A ok in 30.3875s
    test_evgeny_kluev_B ok in 27.1382s
    test_evgeny_kluev_C ok in 14.8131s
    test_ian ok in 26.8318s
    test_jared_goguen ok in 10.0999s
    test_jason_herbburn ok in 21.3870s
    test_tom_karzes ok in 27.9769s
```

Comment: If you leave out the “in Python” part everywhere, this would make a nice problem for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ (or even maths SE)

Comment: I think that one of the following conditions must be true: `n < L / 2 and m < L / 2` or `n > L / 2 and m > L / 2` or `n = 1 and m = L` for 1-based indexing. If so then swapped intervals never overlap and the problem can be solved using simple linear scan.

Comment: @piotrekg2: in other words, in order to check if A is symmetric to B, I have to generate all symmetries for A until I find B? I'm looking for something more efficient.

Comment: @georg: No, that's not what piotrekg2 means.  Just compare each item in B to the item at the same index in A, yielding a sequence of "EQUAL" or "NOT EQUAL" results.  Verify (in O(n) time) that there are exactly 2 nonoverlapping solid blocks of "NOT EQUAL" results that have equal length and begin at equal distances from each end; if this fails then the pair are not symmetric. Otherwise the start and size of the first block tell you a tentative n and m, and you can now verify (in O(n) time) that these tentative values are correct by comparing the m items at A[n:m] with the m items at B[L-m:L-n].

Comment: @j_random_hacker: there can be just one such block, `A=0123, B=0213`.

Comment: @georg: That's true.  That case doesn't complicate things, however -- m must be exactly half its width, and it must begin and end an equal distance from each end.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I'm afraid I don't follow - care to post some code?

Comment: @georg: Fredrik Savje's answer is a clear description of what I'm saying.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: **Hint**: Write an algorithm that, given two permutations *known to be symmetric*, determines n and m. This should be easy in O(L) by looking where the permutations differ. Now to test if two *general* permutations are symmetric, run the fast algorithm to estimate n and m, then check the permutations are (n, m)-symmetric. Both steps O(L).

Comment: Just to clarify: can `n == m`? Is `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` symmetric with `[0 6 2 3 4 5 1 7]`?

Comment: @Ian: I think `m > n` should be required, if n == m, then `A[n:m]==[]`. Thanks!

Comment: @georg OK, one last question. If the conditions  - `A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n]`
and  `- B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]` are satisfied *but* all other elements are *not* in place, can they be considered `symmetric`?

Comment: @Ian: no, because otherwise any permutation would be "symmetric".

Comment: @georg OK, got it! I am posting my solution. :)

Comment: @Ian: be sure to check it with the gist ;) Good luck!

Comment: On the terminology: A swap of two continuous subsequences is a **block transposition**, see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659190028F) (definition 4). So I'd call these _symmetric block transpositions._

Comment: @georg I updated my answer for faster computation. And I have a question: can the list be something like `'01224134'` for example? That is, there are multiple items inside. Would you try `run(fns, '01224134')`?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, suppose x > m > n. (A[n:x] == B[L-x:L-n] and B[n:x] == A[L-x:L-n]) => (A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n] and B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]). So problem reduces to search for a common sub string of size 2 in A[0:L/2+1] and B[L/2-1:L], more or less (you got to verify the symmetry exists etc.. which is O(1)), which is O(n).

Comment: @Ian: no, all elements are unique. Permutations of non-unique elements is an interesting but different problem.

Comment: @S.Pinkus: is something like `A[x:y]==B[u,v]` really `O(1)`?

Comment: @georg No that is the O(n) part. The verifying symmetry (B[n:m] also equals A[L-m:L-n]) is the O(1) part. It's O(1) because we only need to test 2 positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rewrote the code without some of the complexity (and errors).

```
def test_o_o(a, b):

    L = len(a)
    H = L//2
    n, m = 0, H-1

    # find the first difference in the left-side
    while n < H:
        if a[n] != b[n]: break
        n += 1
    else: return

    # find the last difference in the left-side
    while m > -1:
        if a[m] != b[m]: break 
        m -= 1
    else: return

    # for slicing, we want end_index+1
    m += 1

    # compare each slice for equality
    # order: beginning, block 1, block 2, middle, end
    if (a[0:n] == b[0:n] and \
        a[n:m] == b[L-m:L-n] and \
        b[n:m] == a[L-m:L-n] and \
        a[m:L-m] == b[m:L-m] and \
        a[L-n:L] == b[L-n:L]):

        return n, m
```

The implementation is both elegant and efficient.

The `break` into `else: return` structures ensure that the function returns at the soonest possible point. They also validate that `n` and `m` have been set to valid values, but this does not appear to be necessary when explicitly checking the slices. These lines can be removed with no noticeable impact on the timing.

Explicitly comparing the slices will also short-circuit as soon as one evaluates to `False`.

Originally, I checked whether a permutation existed by transforming `b` into `a`:

```
b = b[:]
b[n:m], b[L-m:L-n] = b[L-m:L-n], b[n:m]
if a == b:
   return n, m
```

But this is slower than explicitly comparing the slices. Let me know if the algorithm doesn't speak for itself and I can offer further explanation (maybe even proof) as to why it works and is minimal.

Comment: Thanks! This version reports false positives: `test_o_o ERR [(4, 5), 'should be None', 'for', '012354']`

Comment: @georg I rewrote the code using a new algorithm and it appears to be quicker than the code by alexis

Comment: @georg It's not really a "new algorithm," it's more like a "different implementation that doesn't have the errors and overhead that the original implementation had." It's still equivalent to the pseudo-code that Fredrik Savje provided.

Comment: Your code is the fastest and hence the winner. Congrats!

Comment: As a further optimizaition, you can eliminate `a[0:n] == b[0:n]`, because you already know that they are equal, and compare `a[H:L-m]` instead of `a[m:L-m]`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the working solution for the question:

```
def isSymmetric(A, B):
    L = len(A) #assume equivalent to len(B), modifying this would be as simple as checking if len(A) != len(B), return []
    la = L//2 # half-list length
    Al = A[:la]
    Ar = A[la:]
    Bl = B[:la]
    Br = B[la:]
    for i in range(la):
        lai = la - i #just to reduce the number of computation we need to perform
        for j in range(1, lai + 1):
            k = lai - j #same here, reduce computation
            if Al[i] != Br[k] or Ar[k] != Bl[i]: #the key for efficient computation is here: do not proceed unnecessarily
                 continue
            n = i #written only for the sake of clarity. i is n, and we can use i directly
            m = i + j
            if A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n] and B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]: #possibly symmetric
                if A[0:n] == B[0:n] and A[m:L-m] == B[m:L-m] and A[L-n:] == B[L-n:]:
                    return [n, m]
    return []
```

As you have mentioned, though the idea *looks* simple, but it is actually quite a *tricky* one. Once we *see* the patterns, however, the implementation is straight-forward.

The central idea of the solution is this single line:

```
if Al[i] != Br[k] or Ar[k] != Bl[i]: #the key for efficient computation is here: do not proceed unnecessarily
```

All other lines are just either direct code translation from the problem statement or optimization made for more efficient computation.

---

There are few steps involved in order to find the solution:

**Firstly**, we need to split the each both list `A`and list `B` into two half-lists (called `Al`, `Ar`, `Bl`, and `Br`). Each half-list would contain half of the members of the original lists:

```
Al = A[:la]
Ar = A[la:]
Bl = B[:la]
Br = B[la:]
```

---

**Secondly**, to make the **evaluation** efficient, the goal here is to find what I would call **pivot index** to decide whether a *position in the list (index)* is worth evaluated or not to check if the lists are symmetric. This **pivot index** is the central idea to find an *efficient* solution. So I would try to elaborate it quite a bit:

Consider the left half part of the `A` list, suppose you have a member like this:

```
Al = [al1, al2, al3, al4, al5, al6]
```

We can **imagine** that there is a corresponding **index** list for the mentioned list like this

```
Al  = [al1, al2, al3, al4, al5, al6]
iAl = [0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5  ] #corresponding index list, added for explanation purpose
```

*(Note: the reason why I mention of imagining a corresponding index list is for ease of explanation purposes)*

Likewise, we can imagine that the other three lists may have similar index lists. Let's name them `iAr`, `iBl`, and `iBr` respectively and they are all having identical members with `iAl`.

It is the **index** of the lists which would really matter for us to look into - in order to solve the problem.

---

Here is what I mean: suppose we have two parameters:

1. **index** (let's give a variable name `i` to it, and I would use symbol `^` for current `i`)
2. **length** (let's give a variable name `j` to it, and I would use symbol `==` to visually represent its length value)

for each **evaluation** of the **index** element in `iAl` - then each **evaluation** would mean:

> Given an **index** value `i` and length value of `j` in `iAl`, do
>   something to determine if it is worth to check for symmetric
>   qualifications starting from that **index** and with that **length**
>   (Hence the name **pivot index** come).

Now, let's take example of one **evaluation** when `i = 0` and `j = 1`. The evaluation can be illustrated as follow:

```
iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 0
       == <-- now this has length (j) of 1
```

---

In order for those **index** `i` and **length** `j` to be worth evaluated further, then the counterpart `iBr` must have the *same* item value with the *same* **length** but on different **index** (let's name it **index** `k`)

```
iBr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                      ^ <-- must compare the value in this index to what is pointed by iAl
                      == <-- must evaluate with the same length = 1
```

For example, for the above case, this is a *possible* "symmetric" permutation just for the two lists `Al-Br` (we will consider the other two lists `Ar-Bl` later):

```
Al = [0, x, x, x, x, x] #x means don't care for now
Br = [x, x, x, x, x, 0]
```

At this moment, it is good to note that

> It **won't worth evaluating further** if even the above condition is not
>   true

And this is where you get the algorithm to be more **efficient**; that is, by selectively evaluating only the **few** possible cases among all possible cases. And how to find the few possible cases?

> By trying to find **relationship between indexes and lengths** of the
>   four lists. That is, for a given **index** `i` and **length** `j` in a
>   list (say `Al`), what must be the **index** `k` in the **counterpart**
>   list (in the case is `Br`). Length for the counterpart list need not
>   be found because it is the same as in the list (that is `j`).

Having know that, let's now proceed further to see if we can see more patterns in the **evaluation** process.

---

Consider now the effect of length (`j`). For example, if we are to evaluate from **index** `0`, but the length is `2` then the counterpart list would need to have different **index** `k` evaluated than when the length is `1`

```
iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 0
       ===== <-- now this has length (j) of 2

iBr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                   ^ <-- must compare the value in this index to what is pointed by iAl
                   ===== <-- must evaluate with the same length = 2
```

Or, for the illustration above, what really matters fox `i = 0` and `y = 2` is something like this:

```
# when i = 0 and y = 2
Al = [0, y, x, x, x, x] #x means don't care for now
Br = [x, x, x, x, 0, y] #y means to be checked later
```

Take a look that the above pattern is a bit different from when `i = 0` and `y = 1` - the index position for `0` **value** in the example is shifted:

```
# when i = 0 and y = 1, k = 5
Al = [0, x, x, x, x, x] #x means don't care for now
Br = [x, x, x, x, x, 0]

# when i = 0 and y = 2, k = 4
Al = [0, y, x, x, x, x] #x means don't care for now
Br = [x, x, x, x, 0, y] #y means to be checked later
```

Thus, **length** shifts *where* the **index** of the counterpart list must be checked. In the first case, when `i = 0` and `y = 1`, then the `k = 5`. But in the second case, when `i = 0` and `y = 1`, then the `k = 4`. Thus we found the **pivot indexes** relationship when we change the **length** `j` for a fixed **index** `i` (in this case being `0`) unto the counterpart list **index** `k`.

---

Now, consider the effects of **index** `i` with fixed **length** `j` for counterpart list **index** `k`. For example, let's fix the **length** as `y = 4`, then for **index** `i = 0`, we have:

```
iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 0
       ========== <-- now this has length (j) of 4

iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 1
          ========== <-- now this has length (j) of 4

iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
             ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 2
             ========== <-- now this has length (j) of 4

#And no more needed
```

In the above example, it can be seen that we need to evaluate **3** possibilities for the given `i` and `j`, but if the **index** `i` is changed to `1` with the same length `j = 4`:

```
iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 1
          ========== <-- now this has length (j) of 4

iAl = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
             ^ <-- now evaluate this index (i) = 2
             ========== <-- now this has length (j) of 4
```

Note that we only need to evaluate **2** possibilities. Thus the increase of **index** `i` decreases the number of possible cases to be evaluated!

---

With all the above patterns found, we *almost* found all the basis we need to make the algorithm works. But to complete that, we need to find the relationship between **indexes** which appear in `Al-Br` pair for a given `[i, j] => [k, j]` with the **indexes** in `Ar-Bl` pair for the same `[i, j]`.

Now, we can actually see that they are simply **mirroring** the relationship we found in `Al-Br` pair!

*(IMHO, this is really beautiful! and thus I think term "symmetric" permutation is not far from truth)*

For example, if we have the following `Al-Br` pair evaluated with `i = 0` and `y = 2`

```
Al = [0, y, x, x, x, x] #x means don't care for now
Br = [x, x, x, x, 0, y] #y means to be checked later
```

Then, to make it **symmetric**, we must have the corresponding `Ar-Bl`:

```
Ar = [x, x, x, x, 3, y] #x means don't care for now
Bl = [3, y, x, x, x, x] #y means to be checked later
```

The **indexing** of `Al-Br` pair is **mirroring** (or, is symmetric to) the indexing of `Ar-Bl` pair!

---

Therefore, combining all the pattern we found above, we now could find the **pivot indexes** for evaluating `Al`, `Ar`, `Bl`, and `Br`.

> We only need to check the values of the lists in the **pivot index**
>   first. If the values of the lists in the **pivot indexes** of `Al`, `Ar`, `Bl`, and `Br`
>   matches in the **evaluation** ***then and only then*** we need to check
>   for symmetric criteria (thus making the computation efficient!)

---

Putting up all the knowledge above into code, the following is the resulting `for-loop` Python code to check for symmetricity:

```
for i in range(len(Al)): #for every index in the list
    lai = la - i #just simplification
    for j in range(1, lai + 1): #get the length from 1 to la - i + 1
        k = lai - j #get the mirror index
        if Al[i] != Br[k] or Ar[k] != Bl[i]: #if the value in the pivot indexes do not match
             continue #skip, no need to evaluate
        #at this point onwards, then the values in the pivot indexes match
        n = i #assign n
        m = i + j #assign m
        #test if the first two conditions for symmetric are passed
        if A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n] and B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]: #possibly symmetric
            #if it passes, test the third condition for symmetric, the rests of the elements must stay in its place
            if A[0:n] == B[0:n] and A[m:L-m] == B[m:L-m] and A[L-n:] == B[L-n:]:                   
                return [n, m] #if all three conditions are passed, symmetric lists are found! return [n, m] immediately!
        #passing this but not outside of the loop means 
        #any of the 3 conditions to find symmetry are failed
        #though values in the pivot indexes match, simply continue
return [] #nothing can be found - asymmetric lists
```

And there go you with the symmetric test!

*(OK, this is quite a challenge and it takes quite a while for me to figure out how.)*

Comment: Passes all tests, congratulations! (I have to take time to read your explanations though).

Comment: @JaredGoguen Don't mix the *implementation* with the *explanation*. The *implementation* is very straightforward. It centers around the idea of **given [i,j], find k**. The *explanation* is added to explain *step-by-step* - conceptually and illustratively - *why* it is working. Therefore it is quite *long* (if this is what you mean by *complex*)

Comment: @Ian I'm not mixing the two up, and I do appreciate the effort put into your explanation. But, what I think is the most efficient algorithm assigns `n` to be the first difference and `m` as the last difference between the first halves of the sequences. Then, testing whether these indices produce a "symmetric block transposition" is easy. Check out my algorithm (which, granted, is not explained as thoroughly as yours).

Comment: (Please try and fix `It won't worth evaluating further`. I _did_ find `symmetricity`, but not from sources I consider quotable: please include a link or a definition.)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to implement 3 different algorithms for this task. All of them have O(N) time complexity and require O(1) additional space. Interesting fact: all other answers (known so far) implement 2 of these algorithms (though they not always keep optimal asymptotic time/space complexity). Here is high-level description for each algorithm:

**Algorithm A**

1. Compare the lists, group "non-equal" intervals, make sure there are exactly two such intervals (with special case when intervals meet in the middle).
2. Check if "non-equal" intervals are positioned symmetrically, and their contents is also "symmetrical".

**Algorithm B**

1. Compare first halves of the lists to guess where are "intervals to be exchanged".
2. Check if contents of these intervals is "symmetrical". And make sure the lists are equal outside of these intervals.

**Algorithm C**

1. Compare first halves of the lists to find first mismatched element.
2. Find this mismatched element of first list in second one. This hints the position of "intervals to be exchanged".
3. Check if contents of these intervals is "symmetrical". And make sure the lists are equal outside of these intervals.

There are two alternative implementations for step 1 of each algorithm: (1) using itertools, and (2) using plain loops (or list comprehensions). itertools are efficient for long lists but relatively slow on short lists.

Here is algorithm C with first step implemented using itertools. It looks simpler than other two algorithms (at the end of this post). And it is pretty fast, even for short lists:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def test_C(a, b):
    length = len(a)
    half = length // 2
    mismatches = it.imap(op.ne, a, b[:half]) # compare half-lists

    try:
        n = next(it.compress(it.count(), mismatches))
        nr = length - n
        mr = a.index(b[n], half, nr)
        m = length - mr
    except StopIteration: return None
    except ValueError: return None

    if a[n:m] == b[mr:nr] and b[n:m] == a[mr:nr] \
            and a[m:mr] == b[m:mr] and a[nr:] == b[nr:]:
        return (n, m)
```

---

This could be done using mostly itertools:

```
def test_A(a, b):
    equals = it.imap(op.eq, a, b) # compare lists
    e1, e2 = it.tee(equals)
    l = it.chain(e1, [True])
    r = it.chain([True], e2)
    borders = it.imap(op.ne, l, r) # delimit equal/non-equal intervals
    ranges = list(it.islice(it.compress(it.count(), borders), 5))

    if len(ranges) == 4:
        n1, m1 = ranges[0], ranges[1]
        n2, m2 = ranges[2], ranges[3]
    elif len(ranges) == 2:
        n1, m1 = ranges[0], len(a) // 2
        n2, m2 = len(a) // 2, ranges[1]
    else:
        return None

    if n1 == len(a) - m2 and m1 == len(a) - n2 \
            and a[n1:m1] == b[n2:m2] and b[n1:m1] == a[n2:m2]:
        return (n1, m1)
```

High-level description of this algorithm is already provided in OP comments by @j_random_hacker. Here are some details:

Start with comparing the lists:

```
A  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
B  0 5 6 3 4 1 2 7
=  E N N E E N N E
```

Then find borders between equal/non-equal intervals:

```
=  E N N E E N N E
B  _ * _ * _ * _ *
```

Then determine ranges for non-equal elements:

```
B  _ * _ * _ * _ *
    [1 : 3] [5 : 7]
```

Then check if there are exactly 2 ranges (with special case when both ranges meet in the middle), the ranges themselves are symmetrical, and their contents too.

---

Other alternative is to use itertools to process only half of each list. This allows slightly simpler (and slightly faster) algorithm because there is no need to handle a special case:

```
def test_B(a, b):
    equals = it.imap(op.eq, a, b[:len(a) // 2]) # compare half-lists
    e1, e2 = it.tee(equals)
    l = it.chain(e1, [True])
    r = it.chain([True], e2)
    borders = it.imap(op.ne, l, r) # delimit equal/non-equal intervals
    ranges = list(it.islice(it.compress(it.count(), borders), 2))

    if len(ranges) != 2:
        return None

    n, m = ranges[0], ranges[1]
    nr, mr = len(a) - n, len(a) - m

    if a[n:m] == b[mr:nr] and b[n:m] == a[mr:nr] \
            and a[m:mr] == b[m:mr] and a[nr:] == b[nr:]:
        return (n, m)
```

Comment: +1 for the attribution to j_random_hacker's early comment - I considered this question done before take off.

Answer (score 3):

I build a map of where the characters are in list B, then use that to determine the implied subranges in list A. Once I have the subranges, I can sanity check some of the info, and compare the slices.

If `A[i] == x`, then where does `x` appear in B? Call that position `p`.

I know `i`, the *start* of the left subrange.

I know `L (= len(A))`, so I know `L-i`, the *end* of the right subrange.

If I know `p`, then I know the implied *start* of the right subrange, assuming that B[p] and A[i] are the start of a symmetric pair of ranges. Thus, the OP's `L - m` would be `p` if the lists were symmetric.

Setting `L-m == p` gives me `m`, so I have all four end points.

Sanity tests are:

- n and m are in left half of list(s)
- n <= m (note: OP did not prohibit n == m)
- L-n is in right half of list (computed)
- L-m is in right half (this is a good check for quick fail)

If all those check out, compare A[left] == B[right] and B[left] == A[right]. Return `left` if true.

```
def find_symmetry(a:list, b:list) -> slice or None:

    assert len(a) == len(b)
    assert set(a) == set(b)
    assert len(set(a)) == len(a)

    length = len(a)
    assert length % 2 == 0

    half = length // 2
    b_loc = {bi:n for n,bi in enumerate(b)}

    for n,ai in enumerate(a[:half]):
        L_n = length - 1 - n    # L - n
        L_m = b_loc[ai]         # L - m (speculative)

        if L_m < half:         # Sanity: bail if on wrong side
            continue

        m = b_loc[a[L_n]]  # If A[n] starts range, A[m] ends it.

        if m < n or m > half:   # Sanity: bail if backwards or wrong side
            continue

        left = slice(n, m+1)
        right = slice(L_m, L_n+1)

        if a[left] == b[right] and \
            b[left] == a[right]:
            return left

    return None

res = find_symmetry(
        [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ],
        [ 10, 15, 16, 13, 14, 11, 12, 17, ])
assert res == slice(1,3)

res = find_symmetry(
    [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ],
    [ 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, ])
assert res is None

res = find_symmetry("abcdefghijklmn", "nbcdefghijklma")
assert res == slice(0,1)

res = find_symmetry("abcdefghijklmn", "abjklfghicdmen")
assert res == slice(3,4)

res = find_symmetry("abcdefghijklmn", "ancjkfghidelmb")
assert res == slice(3,5)

res = find_symmetry("abcdefghijklmn", "bcdefgaijklmnh")
assert res is None

res = find_symmetry("012345", "013245")
assert res == slice(2,3)
```

Comment: Fails for `012345, 013245` - see the gist

Comment: Fixed. Changed half+1 to half in slice, <= to < in comparison. Added test case.

Comment: Thanks, now it returns false positives `test_austin_hastings ERR [(2, 3), 'should be None', 'for', '013254']`

Answer (score 3):

This does the right thing:

```
Br = B[L//2:]+B[:L//2]
same_full = [a==b for (a,b) in zip(A, Br)]
same_part = [a+b for (a,b) in zip(same_full[L//2:], same_full[:L//2])]

for n, vn in enumerate(same_part):
    if vn != 2:
        continue
    m = n
    for vm in same_part[n+1:]:
        if vm != 2:
            break
        m+=1

    if m>n:
        print("n=", n, "m=", m+1)
```

I'm pretty sure you could do the counting a bit bettter, but... meh

Comment: Fails for `012345, 013245` - see the gist.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following pseudocode should work:

1. Find the first element `i` for which `A[i] != B[i]`, set `n = i`. If no such element, return `success`. If `n >= L/2`, return `fail`.
2. Find the first element `i > n` for which `A[i] == B[i]`, set `m = i`. If no such element or `m > L/2`, set `m = L/2`.
3. Check so `A[0:n] == B[0:n]`, `A[n:m] == B[L-m:L-n]`, `B[n:m] == A[L-m:L-n]`,  `A[m:L-m] == B[m:L-m]` and `A[L-n:L] == B[L-n:L]`. If all are true, return `success`. Else, return `fail`.

Complexity is O(n) which should be the lowest possible as one always needs to compare all elements in the lists.

Comment: @georg It turns out my implementation is equivalent to this pseudocode

Comment: @FredrikSavje This appears to be the fast method at the moment

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution that passes my tests, and yours:

1. Compare the inputs, looking for a subsequence that does not match.
2. Transform `A` by transposing the mismatched subsequence according to the rules. Does the result match `B`?

The algorithm is O(N); there are no embedded loops, explicit or implicit.

In step 1, I need to detect the case where the swapped substrings are adjacent. This can only happen in the middle of the string, but I found it easier to just look out for the first element of the moved piece (`firstval`). Step 2 is simpler (and hence less error-prone) than explicitly checking all the constraints.

```
def compare(A, B):
    same = True
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A,B)):
        if same and a != b:  # Found the start of a presumed transposition
            same = False
            n = i
            firstval = a  # First element of the transposed piece
        elif (not same) and (a == b or b == firstval):  # end of the transposition
            m = i
            break

    # Construct the transposed string, compare it to B
    origin = A[n:m] 
    if n == 0:  # swap begins at the edge
        dest = A[-m:]
        B_expect = dest + A[m:-m] + origin
    else:
        dest = A[-m:-n]
        B_expect = A[:n] + dest + A[m:-m] + origin + A[-n:]

    return bool(B_expect == B)
```

Sample use:

```
>>> compare("01234567", "45670123")
True
```

**Bonus:** I believe the name for this relationship would be **"symmetric block transposition".** A **block transposition** swaps two subsequences, taking `ABCDE` to `ADCBE`. (See definition 4 [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659190028F); I actually found this by googling "ADCBE"). I've added "symmetric" to the name to describe the length conditions.

Comment: Passes all tests. Good job!

Comment: Thanks! But I just looked at the gist-- shouldn't you be testing with some variety in the input length? Some corner cases certainly need more than six elements.

Comment: Right, I added more sequences - this makes a little difference though.

Comment: Also added timings, your code appears to be significantly faster than others ;)

Answer (score 3):

Make a list (ds) of indices where the first halves of the two lists differ.
A possible n is the first such index, the last such index is m - 1.
Check if valid symmetry.  len(ds) == m - n makes sure there aren't any gaps.

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def test(a, b):
    sz = len(a)
    ds = list(it.compress(it.count(), map(op.ne, a[:sz//2], b[:sz//2])))
    n,m = ds[0], ds[-1]+1
    if a[n:m] == b[sz-m:sz-n] and b[n:m] == a[sz-m:sz-n] and len(ds) == m - n:
        return n,m
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: This seems to fail: `test_roottwo ERR [None, 'should be equal to', (2, 3), 'for', '013245']`

Comment: Changed in the gist, but still no luck ;(

Comment: When I run `test('013245', '012345')` it returns `(2, 3)`.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a py2 vs 3 confusion. I tested in py2.

Comment: That was it.  In 2.7, map() pads short sequences with None.  In 3.x, map() stops when it reaches the end of the shortest sequence. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an O(N) solution which passes the test code:

```
def sym_check(a, b):
    cnt = len(a)

    ml = [a[i] == b[i] for i in range(cnt)]

    sl = [i for i in range(cnt) if (i == 0 or ml[i-1]) and not ml[i]]
    el = [i+1 for i in range(cnt) if not ml[i] and (i == cnt-1 or ml[i+1])]

    assert(len(sl) == len(el))

    range_cnt = len(sl)

    if range_cnt == 1:
        start1 = sl[0]
        end2 = el[0]

        if (end2 - start1) % 2 != 0:
            return None

        end1 = (start1 + end2) // 2
        start2 = end1

    elif range_cnt == 2:

        start1, start2 = sl
        end1, end2 = el

    else:
        return None

    if end1 - start1 != end2 - start2:
        return None

    if start1 != cnt - end2:
        return None

    if a[start1:end1] != b[start2:end2]:
        return None

    if b[start1:end1] != a[start2:end2]:
        return None

    return start1, end1
```

I only tested it with Python 2, but I believe it will also work with Python 3.

It identifies the ranges where the two lists differ.  It looks for two such ranges (if there is only one such range, it tries to divide it in half).  It then checks that both ranges are the same length and in the proper positions relative to each other.  If so, then it checks that the elements in the ranges match.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another version:

```
def compare(a, b):
    i_zip = list(enumerate(zip(a, b)))
    llen = len(a)
    hp = llen // 2

    def find_index(i_zip):
        for i, (x, y) in i_zip:
            if x != y:
                return i
        return i_zip[0][0]

    # n and m are determined by the unmoved items:
    n = find_index(i_zip[:hp])
    p = find_index(i_zip[hp:])
    m = llen - p
    q = llen - n
    # Symmetric?
    if a[:n] + a[p:q] + a[m:p] + a[n:m] + a[q:] != b:
        return None
    return n, m
```

This solution is based on:

1. All validly permuted list pairs A, B adhering to the symmetry requirement will have the structure:

   `A = P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5
    B = P1 + P4 + P3 + P2 + P5
           ^n  ^m ^hp ^p ^q     <- indexes`

   ,len(P1) == len(P5) and len(P2) == len(P4)
2. Therefore the 3 last lines of the above function will determine the correct solution provided the indexes `n`, `m` are correctly determined. (`p` & `q` are just mirror indexes of `m` & `n`)
3. Finding `n` is a matter of determining when items of A and B start to diverge. Next the same method is applied to finding `p` starting from midpoint `hp`. `m` is just mirror index of `p`. All involved indexes are found and the solution emerges.